# Setting check boxes on CustomTableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift

I set a UIButton on CustomTableViewCells.

I would like to switch the image of UIButton when selected, but the default image does not change after I select again.

[image]
    class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setup()
}

private func setup() {
    self.myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for:.normal)
    self.myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for:.highlighted)

}
```

Comment: @Nirav D Single check selection would be nice!

Comment: I can not add action outlet with IBOutlet as there is no such option as I uploaded photo

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `highlight` and you can change this property when called `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` in the `TableView`

For Example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("This is your Answer... \(indexPath.row)")

    let newSelectedView = tableView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ChoiceCell

    //important
    newSelectedView.highlight.hidden = false

    if self.selectedIndex != -1 && self.selectedIndex != indexPath.row {
        let indexPathSelected = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.selectedIndex, inSection: 0)
        let prevSelected = tableView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPathSelected) as! ChoiceCell

        //important
        prevSelected.highlight.hidden = true
    }

    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row

}
```